# Publicizing a constructor in private inheritance

Tags: c++

During private inheritance the public member variable or member functions of Base class can be assigned back the public access specifier in Derived.
But can we do the same for a public constructor of Base class?

I tried it as follows,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class base
{
      public:
             base(){}
             void print(){ puts("In print"); }
};

class derived : private base
{
      public:
             base::print;
             base::base;   /* Throws an error - Declaration doesnt declare anything*/
             void display(){ puts("In display"); }
};

int main()
{
    derived dObj;
}
```

It throws an error "Declaration doesnt declare anything"
Is what I am trying valid?

Comment: This is interesting. But why do you want to inherit as private then provide public access?

Comment: Without C++11, you cannot inherit constructors from the base class -- they are either invoked by the constructor of the derived class explicitly, or implicitly. For the other methods from `base` that you wish to use in `derived`, you would need the `using` keyword.

Comment: @tuxuday - I read that if we inherit privately and want to give public access only to one or few members but not the entire base class we can do so. It works for member variables and functions. I just tried for the constructor too.

Comment: @void-pointer - So it means even after inheritance constructors of base class are not inherited by the derived. In fact, if not explicitly defined, compiler generates a separate default constructor for each of the class's in inheritance hierarchy?

Comment: No, constructors are never automatically inherited -- in C++11, you can explicitly inherit all of the base class's constructors via `using`. Regardless of whether or not the constructors for the descendants of `derived` were automatically generated, they are still not inherited by `derived.`

Comment: @void-pointer- thanks..i got it now :-)

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `using` syntax. But it does not make much sense of `using` the base class constructor. I am guessing you want to initialize your base class, right? You can do it like:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class base
{
      public:
             base(){}
             void print(){ puts("In print"); }
};

class derived : private base
{
      public:
             using base::print;
             derived() : base() {} // initialize base class
             void display(){ puts("In display"); }
};

int main()
{
    derived dObj;
}
```

Comment: Yes I can initialize base class constructor that way, I was just trying out if I can reassign public access to base class constructor in derived.

Comment: well, then why not give it a [trial](http://ideone.com/eAr02). What you will get is an error: `'base::base’ names constructor`.

Comment: @user2k5: because a trial only tells you how a compiler behaves, not what the Standard says the behavior should be. If I recall correctly, C++11 makes the syntax legal, yet the version of gcc at ideone (even for C++0x) does not implement it yet.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I know that C++11 supports inheriting (all or nothing) constructors from base class. Above I just want to show that it just does not make any sense of `using` base class constructor without C++11.